# List directories and files in a tree structure

Tags: shell, sed

I'm trying to list directories and files contained within them in the following way:

```
 DIR: name1
   file1
   file2
   file3
   DIR: name2
     file4
     file5
     file6
  DIR: name3
   file7
```

So far, I've come up with a way to get a tree structure using `find` and `sed`, like this:

```
find . | sed -e "s/[^-][^\/]*\//  |/g"
```

I don't know how to distinguish between files and directories to be able to add `DIR:` in front of the names of the directories.

Comment: There is a `tree` command in some distros. You *can* simply `ls -F`, but you *shouldn't* parse `ls`. If you must, `stat` is your expensive friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have `tree` you can use GNU `find` to identify directories vs files:

```
$ find . -mindepth 1 -printf '%y %p\n'
d ./dir1
d ./dir1/dir2
f ./dir1/dir2/fileA
d ./dir1/dir3
f ./dir1/fileC
f ./fileB
```

and then parse the output with awk to create the indenting, etc.

```
$ find . -mindepth 1 -printf '%y %p\n' |
    awk '$1=="d"{sub(/.*\//,"&DIR: ")} {gsub(/[^\/]*\//,"  ")} 1'
  DIR: dir1
    DIR: dir2
      fileA
    DIR: dir3
    fileC
  fileB
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this with tree and GNU sed:

```
tree -F coreutils-8.9 | sed -r 's|── (.*)/$|── DIR: \1|'
```

Output (example):

```
coreutils-8.9
├── ABOUT-NLS
├── bootstrap.conf
├── DIR: build-aux
│   ├── announce-gen*
│   ├── arg-nonnull.h
│   └── ylwrap*
├── cfg.mk
├── ChangeLog
├── DIR: doc
│   ├── ChangeLog-2007
│   └── constants.texi
└── TODO
```

I assume that the file names don't contain "── ".